# Unexpected data found. Trailing data Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7, php-carbon

I am currently upgrading from Laravel 6 to 7 and I am faced with the following error "Unexpected data found. Trailing data".  I am unable to figure out why this issue is occuring. I have atatched the dataset where it's occuring

[image]

Comment: You should inspect the stack trace and dump the string that has been passed in the `DateTime::createFromFormat` or constructor, it may be microseconds passed and the format expect only second-precision.

Comment: @KyleK that is indeed my problem. It always happens with the same column of the same model, but in the database, that field contains a regular mysql timestamp (without microseconds). How can I find out where the microseconds are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to serialize the date. Add the following to your models

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```